# How to perform Validation on Unsupervised learning?

Tags: cross-validation, validation, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

Since I consider **Unsupervised** learning, I don't have any ground truth to compare with, during the validation phase. So, is there any standard method to deal with it?

---

Additional informations:

- in my particular case, "validation" is a cross-validation indeed.
- I'm developing a custom binary anomaly detection model which labels dataset records in 2 classes: "normal" and "abnormal"

Answer (score 5):

I realize this comes very late, but perhaps it is still useful for anyone looking into the same subject and coming across this question. I don't believe there is a standard method, as you ask. However, I worked on this about two years ago for my MSc thesis in Statistical Science: https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/statscience/2017-2018/2018_08_27_masterthesis_debakker.pdf. I think Chapter 2.4 (page 18-30) might be of interest with regard to your question and the following is about/in that chapter.

I worked out a v-fold cross-validation scheme to optimize a generic value for *k*, the number of clusters to look for in a data set. I reviewed and used/adapted several existing validation indices to measure "goodness of fit" of a clustering; many exist since, as you pointed out, there is no ground thruth in unsupervised learning, so there is no standard way to measure how well a clustering looking for a certain *k* number of clusters is doing. See also the literature study in my thesis, if you want an overview (note it's two years old by now and I have not followed the literature since). A personal favourite is Prediction Strength by Tibshirani and Walther (https://doi.org/10.1198/106186005X59243). In principle, any such cluster number validation index could in theory be implemented in the framework I designed (see image below, from thesis page 30).

[image]

Subsequently I applied this method to a data set I had at hand back then, but that will be of less interest for you, I assume.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it will be considered and answer as in fact is a pointer to a possible answer, but at the same time, I don't have enough reputation to add it as a comment. So it will go here, maybe someone with more rights can move it as comment.

I'm struggling with this theme too and today I found this PhD thesis

["CROSS-VALIDATION FOR UNSUPERVISED LEARNING"  by Patrick O. Perry
September 2009 - Stanford University](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3052)

in the abstract the author states

> This thesis discusses some extensions of cross-validation to
>   unsupervised learning, specifically focusing on the problem of
>   choosing how many principal components to keep. We introduce the
>   latent factor model, define an objective criterion, and show how CV
>   can be used to estimate the intrinsic dimensionality of a data set.
>   Through both simulation and theory, we demonstrate that 
>   cross-validation is a valuable tool for unsupervised learning.

http://ptrckprry.com/reports/